# Différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, passé-simple

Je sais que le passé simple ne s'emploie presque jamais à l'oral, où il a été remplacé par le passé composé. Cependant, j'ai déjà lu des textes dans lesquels les deux temps ont été employés côte à côte. Quelle est la nuance entre les deux ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Le passé simple et le passé composé indiquent tous deux que l'action s'est **produite** et **terminée** dans le passé.

Le passé composé indique que l'action s'est produite dans un temps **indéfini**, généralement récent, et peut avoir des **conséquences** dans le présent.

Exemples :

> J'ai trop mangé ce midi.
>   Il a emprunté une importante somme d'argent.

Le passé simple indique que l'action s'est produite dans un temps **défini** et n'a **pas de conséquence** dans le présent.

Exemples :

> La bataille de Marignan eut lieu en 1515.
>       Jean se leva, sortit de la pièce et ne revint plus.

Le passé composé est utilisé à l'oral et à l'écrit, tandis que le passé simple n'est en général utilisé qu'à l'écrit.

L'utilisation des deux temps dans une même phrase est improbable et peut être un effet de style.

Comment: Bien que je suis d'accord avec la definition. Je trouve que le mot 'consequence' est peu concis.

Comment: D'autant que dire que la bataille de Marignan n'a pas de conséquence sur le présent est peut-être un peu osé. http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Marignan#Les_cons.C3.A9quences

Comment: Merci ! Au moins j'ai compris que le passé simple c'est déjà passer et n'as pas de conséquences dans le présent et le passé composé si.

Comment: "La bataille de Marignan a eu lieu en 1515" est tout à fait correct également bien que moins littéraire.

Comment: The reason why I hate grammar: "un temps indéfini" and then, right away, as the  example goes: "J'ai trop mangé ce midi." Ce midi, damn it! Is it indéfini? What would be "défini" then? Á 12:00:00? And not a single comment on this apparent contradiction.

Answer (score 12):

La nuance entre les deux est assez faible. Je pense que la préférence pour le passé composé vient du fait qu'il est beaucoup plus simple à conjuguer que le passe simple (qui n'est pas du tout simple contrairement à ce que son nom indique).

De plus en plus, le passé composé est utilisé à la place du passé simple sans que cela choque l'oreille d'un français.

Néanmoins le passe simple est surtout considéré comme un temps de narration, qui met en valeur une action passée. Alors que les autres temps du passé (passé composé, imparfait, ...) servent plus aux actions secondaires ou à placer l'ambiance. (ex : "Il faisait chaud mais il s'endormit rapidement").

On considère également que le passé simple exprime une action révolue (et brève) qui n'a plus de lien avec le présent alors que le passé composé exprime une action qui a encore une incidence sur le présent.

Comment: Cela ne choque pas du tout à l'écrit. Et puis personne utilise le passé simple en parlant, à quelques exceptions près,

Answer (score 10):

Le passé composé indique juste  que les faits rapportés sont dans le passé par rapport au présent, le temps de l'élocution. Rapporter les faits au passé composé implique une conséquence sur le présent.

Le passé simple, lui, est le temps de l'action ponctuelle dans le vrai passé, n'impliquant ni répétition ni aspect de cadre à l'action

Quant à la juxtaposition du passé simple et du passé composé au sein d'une narration, il doit d'agir d'un effet de style.

Answer (score 3):

- Le passé simple **a les mêmes valeurs que le passé composé**(fait
  ponctuel,durée limitée, succession d'événments), sauf celle de
  l'antériorité par rapport au présent.
- **Dans un récit au passé,le passé simple a les mêmes relations avec
  l'imparfait que le passé composé**.
- Mais la différence de celui-ci, qui rattache le fait ou l'action au
  moment ou l'on parle, il le situe dans **un passé lointain** (sans
  contact avec le présent).
- C'est pourquoi on l'emploie dans la littérature (romans, récit,contes
  pour enfants, biographies , etc.) , surtout à la troisième personne.

Comment: Exactement, en gros, personne utilise le passe simple en parlant à quelques exceptions près. A very interesting question is why French people speaking English use the present perfect instead of simple past in English. They get confused....

Answer (score 2):

Une autre explication pour résoudre la nuance existe entre le passé simple et le passé composé quand on les utilise côte à côte :

Exemple 1 :

(aujourd'hui, je suis retraité) Un jour, quand j'étais enseignant, je sortis de la maison et je me dirigeai à l'école, quand j'y suis arrivé, j'ai vu deux élèves se battre devant le portail , dès qu'ils m'ont vu, ils s'éloignèrent et chacun prît une direction différente de l'autre.

....alors quelle est la différence que l'on constate dans cet exemple? Les deux passés sont utilisés côté à côté.

Avant que je vous cite mon explication, je voudrais que vous sachiez qu'elle n'est pas formelle, c'est juste un point de vue :

- dans les actions où les verbes sont conjugués au passé simple, j'ai insisté sur le verbe, j'ai voulu montrer l'action elle-même, ça veut dire : au moment où je suis arrivé ( mettez l'accent sur le verbe arriver).
- dans les actions où le verbe est conjugué au passé simple, j'ai insisté sur la succession des actions.

Conclusion :

Quand on parle d'une chose qui s'est passée au passé et s'est terminée au présent, on utilise toujours le passé simple, en revanche, si on veut mettre l'accent sur ( souligner) le verbe , on utilise le passé composé.

C'est pour cela que l'utilisation de ces deux passés est un effet de style.
J'aimerais bien avoir pu apporter une explication solide à ce problème.

Exemple 2:

- j'ai fini mon travail : je voudrais dire et porter à votre connaissance que mon travail est fini.
- je sortis de ma maison et me dirigeai vers le marché, sur la route je passai chez mon ami et le pris avec moi.

ici je me base sur la succession des actions ...... Dans cet exemple, si je veux porter à votre connaissance que je suis passé chez mon ami , la phrase devient :

............je suis passé chez mon ami......

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14/635

Answer (score 0):

Vos réponses sont enrichissantes, merci.
Il y a des nuances à considérer.

Exemple dans la même narration:

> Jacob s'exclama: "Depuis tout à l'heure elle n'a pas cessé de me regarder."

À considérer, même la brévité du passé simple lui confère une fonction différente, presque interjective.
Le passé simple n'est pas simple.

Answer (score 0):

Le passé simple est principalement utilisé dans les romans, les contes, les textes historiques ou les biographies de personnages du passé. Il se forme avec le radical du présent et, selon les verbes, des terminaisons qui font besoins.
Pour le passé composé, l'action est précise et achevée; il l'a fait une fois, c'est passé et daté.

Answer (score -2):

Exemples :

> Un jour, alors que j'étais à l'école primaire, j'ai vu, sur la route, un homme hurlant courir vers moi...

Avec, quand il y a deux cas: (A = action qui commence la première, B = celle qui commence en second)

> 1. A quand B : je me douchais lorsque le téléphone sonna. (Action A en train lorsque B arrive).
>    2. Quand A, B, avec deux fois le même temps : Quand je me douchai (passé simple), le téléphone sonna (deux actions qui sont considérées comme allant ensemble)

ou encore

> 3. Quand il se douchait, le téléphone sonnait. Un jour, il jeta son téléphone par la fenêtre. (Imparfait parce que les deux actions vont encore de pair lorsqu'il jette le téléphone).