# Utilisation de temps dans « Boucles d'or et les Trois Ours »

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait, passé-simple

Je lis un conte qui s'appelle *Boucles d'or et les trois ours*. Cette histoire commence à imparfait (du moins je le pense):

> Il était une fois trois ours: un papa ours, une maman ours et un bébé
>   ours. Ils habitaient tous ensemble dans une maison jaune au milieu
>   d'une grande forêt.

Mais le temps grammatical change à la première proposition du deuxième paragraphe:

> Un jour, Maman Ours prépara une grande marmite de porridge délicieux
>   et fumant pour le petit déjeuner.

Quel temps est utilisé ici et pourquoi pas l'imparfait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, en effet, c'est l'imparfait qui est utilisé au début. *« Il était une fois »* est d'ailleurs une formule très caractéristique des contes.

> L'imparfait présente l'action dans son déroulement, en cours d'accomplissement ou répétée durant un moment du passé connu de tous les participants
>   *— [Wikipédia - Imparfait](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l'indicatif)*

L'imparfait est généralement utilisé en alternance avec le passé simple, pour décrire le contexte, présenter les personnages... Le passé simple décrit plus précisément les actions souvent à travers une brève description.

> Employer l'imparfait, **c'est mettre en toile de fond** ou à l'arrière plan ce dont on parle, tandis qu'en employant le passé simple **on met au premier plan** ce dont on parle.
>   *— [Wikipédia - Passé Simple](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple)*

Comment: Est-ce que passé simple est temps fréquemment utilisé en le français moderne ? Est-ce nécessaire de savoir ce temps ?

Comment: On ne retrouve le passé simple qu'à l'écrit, dans les romans notamment. A l'oral, il a plutôt été remplacé par [le passé composé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_compos%C3%A9).

Comment: @Marc Cette question [Différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-le-pass%C3%A9-simple-et-le-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9) t'intéressera peut-être.

Comment: Le passé simple est le temps de la narration. On le trouve principalement à l'écrit, mais c'est aussi le temps utilisé par les conteurs, même avec un public de jeunes enfants.

Comment: @Marc Tout à fait d'accord avec Un Francophone, le passé simple est le temps du récit par excellence, le temps des conteurs et, n'oublions pas, des historiens.

Comment: @Laure, Merci ! Oui, elle est intéressant. Je trouve français  très intéressant ;-)

Comment: @Laure: Ah bon, je croyais que les historiens avaient tendance à utiliser le présent !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, les livres d'histoire que je viens de regarder utilisent tous le passé simple comme temps principal pour les actions.