# L'imparfait est-il un temps du système du discours ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjugaison

J'ai été étonné par [cette image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fonctionnement_des_temps_%C3%A0_l%27indicatif.PNG?uselang=fr) qu'on trouve référencée sur plusieurs articles Wikipédia.

Il me semble en effet que la phrase ci-dessous est correcte :

> Je suis venu te voir ; tu étais occupé.

Or, celle-ci mélangerait un temps du système du discours et un temps du système du récit.

Si l'on en croit [cette page](http://xn--coursdefranais-qjb.net/discours_recit3.html), le mystère serait résolu par le fait que l'imparfait appartiendrait aux deux systèmes. Ce site indique d'ailleurs qu'on ne doit pas mélanger les deux. Enfin, il ne met pas l'imparfait au même niveau que le passé simple dans le système du récit.

Qui se trompe ?

Comment: L'imparfait est irremplaçable, à l'écrit comme à l'oral.

Comment: La page à laquelle tu renvoies ne dit pas qu'« on ne doit pas mélanger les deux » mais qu'il faut éviter de les mélanger à l'écrit. En fait les deux systèmes peuvent très bien se mélanger.  Par ailleurs je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire par « au même niveau » mais ça doit venir du fait que la page que tu regardes n'est pas pas bien faite. Regarde [ceci](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=QzBDAwAAQBAJ&q=%C3%A9nonc%C3%A9+et+%C3%A9nonciation#v=snippet&q=%C3%A9nonc%C3%A9%20et%20%C3%A9nonciation&f=false) pp 46 et 47, peut-être que ça te semblera plus clair.

Comment: Merci @Laure.
- Peux-tu donner un exemple de ce mélange ?
- Par « au même niveau », j'entendais vis-à-vis de la ligne temporelle. L'imparfait désigne-t-il une action antérieure au passé composé ?
- Merci pour cette troisième source. Dommage qu'aucune ne s'accorde complètement.

Comment: Les deux pages présentées donnent des éléments relativement simple pour l'usage des temps. La plupart des temps du français peuvent être utilisés avec plus de valeurs que celles données.

Answer (score 2):

L'imparfait s'utilise pour une action à durée prolongée : l'action se passe dans le passé mais n'est pas finie au moment de la narration (quelque chose de non accompli, d'où le terme "im-parfait"). Le passé composé ou le passé simple sont eux utilisés pour une action accomplie (cfr [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-le-pass%C3%A9-simple-et-le-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9) pour les différences) .

Ceci étant dit, c'est plutôt sur la notion de récit et de discours qu'il faut s'attarder pour répondre à votre question.

- Soit on raconte un fait présent auquel on participe, c'est le discours. Dans ce cas, on ne peut pas utiliser l'imparfait car celui-ci concerne une action qui n'était pas accomplie dans le passé (dans un discours, si une action à laquelle je participe n'est pas accomplie, elle a lieu au présent).
- Soit on rapporte simplement un fait passé : c'est un récit. L'imparfait a alors toute sa place.

Vu que le passé composé peut encore avoir une influence sur le présent,  le passé composé se retrouve dans le discours. Je pense qu'on devrait, en théorie, systématiquement remplacer le passé composé par le passé simple dans un récit. Votre exemple devrait donc s'écrire :

```
Je vins te voir; tu étais occupé.
```

Mais, en pratique, on utilise de plus en plus le passé composé à la place du passé simple, même à l'écrit. Le mélange des deux temps est donc tout à fait possible dans un récit. L'action du passé simple ou composé se situe alors pendant l'action à l'imparfait.

```
A) Il a plu alors que je me promenais. 

B) Je me suis promené pendant qu'il pleuvait.
```

En A, j'ai été surpris par une averse pendant ma promenade. En B, j'ai commencé ma promenade en sachant qu'il pleuvait dehors.