# passé simple ou passé composé, différence d'utilisation

Tags: conjugaison

J'ai toujours eu des difficultés à savoir à quel temps mettre mes verbes dans mes écrits.

les sites webs et livres de français expliquent toujours d'une façon très simpliste qui ne m'aident absolument pas. **Si je raconte une histoire au passé composé, que se passe-t-il si je mets un verbe au passé simple ? qu'est ce que cela signifie ?**

exemple de phrase où je ne sais pas quel temps utiliser :

> Puis il a fallu rentrer. En se levant, il est tombé / il tomba
>   l'entrainant dans sa chute.

et je trouve bizarre de continuer au passé simple derrière la deuxième phrase.

Comment: Vous ne pouvez poser que des questions d'importance limitée (sur l'emploi du passé simple plutôt que du passé composé et vice versa, par exemple, (après avoir vérifié que la réponse n'existe pas déjà)) ; vous pouvez proposer autant de questions que vous le désirez, mais seulement sur des points très spécifiques. Donc recommencez avec de petites questions.

Comment: je ne comprends pas votre remarque. Je peux comprendre que je pose plusieurs questions, mais elles se recoupent toutes vers une même interrogation : comment manier le passé ? Les "petites" questions comme vous les appelez n'en sont pas, ce sont des balises pour ceux qui me répondent. En tout cas c'est comme ça que je le vois.

Comment: Cela demande tout simplement trop de sections contenues en elles-mêmes, trop d'unités de savoir linguistiques individuelles, ce qui ne convient pas sur le présent site. Cependant, si une question de recoupement vous vient à l'esprit, vous posez alors une nouvelle question ; ça ne gêne personne, au contraire, le plus de question le plus d'importance pour le site.

Comment: j'ai mis l’interrogation principale en gras. Est-ce plus clair ?

Comment: Oui, ça va pour un début mais n'oubliez pas, votre titre doit résumer la question ; donc ajustez votre titre et supprimez ce qu'il y a en trop dans le texte de la question. (Soyez sure aussi que cette question que vous posez n'a pas déjà été posée, sinon elle ne sera pas acceptée.)

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Cette question reste beaucoup trop vague. " Pourrait-on svp m'expliquer quels temps vont ensemble et comment les utiliser ?" : ce site ne donne pas de cours de français. Il faudrait lire [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) et reposer une question plus précise (ou enlever certaines phrases trop générales). Si vous faites une citation, il faut dire où vous l'avez lue ou d'où elle est tirée.

Comment: Si votre question revient à demander la différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé, la question a déjà été posée plusieurs fois et donc soyez très précise pour montrer en quoi les autres réponses ne vous conviennent pas. [Différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-le-pass%c3%a9-simple-et-le-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9), par exemple. Plus de nombreuses questions sur l'utilisation de l'un ou de l'autre en particulier.

Comment: merci pour votre commentaire. J'ai bien pris connaissance de ça. Je ne suis pas nouvelle sur stackexchange. Par contre je ne crois pas que vous ayez lu ma discussion avec @LPH. J'ai demandé à répondre à la question en gras, qui n'est absolument pas celle que vous citez. Peut-être ne suis-je pas clair, et à ce moment svp dites moi comment changer ma question. Je demande explicitement comment le passé composé et le passé simple inter réagissent.

Comment: Supprimez la seconde phrase ; après cela il n'y aura plus aucun doute. Supprimez aussi « par exemple »

Comment: merci pour votre aide, c'est fait.

Comment: J'avais bien tout lu avant d'écrire - je citais une phrase que vous avez retirée depuis (*cf*, [revision history](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/38416/revisions). Par ailleurs la phrase en gras a  moins d'importance que le titre de la question. Si pour vous la phrase en gras doit avoir plus d'importance il faudrait la mettre en titre.  Pour que votre question soit moins vague, enlevez « exemple de phrase », et dites où vous avez lu ce passage. Et aussi, quand vous répondez à quelqu'un mentionnez @[nom] si plusieurs personnes interviennent.

Comment: j'écris, c'est un exemple de phrases où ce matin même j'étais confrontée à la difficulté du choix du temps.

Comment: On peut bien sûr avoir les deux non seulement dans un même texte, mais aussi dans une même phrase. Extrait du journal *Le Monde* de ce soir: « Ses efforts ont été sabordés par un de ses amis, Nicholas Negroponte, qui aida à fonder le laboratoire en 1985... » le passé simple se référe à une action plus éloignée que celle au passé composé, le passé composé ayant un lien avec le présent. On peut trouver de nombreux exemples semblables. Dans cet exemple précis le passé simple a la même valeur que le plus-que-parfait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-le-pass%c3%a9-simple-et-le-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certaines notions de base sont formulées dans la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4210) ;

> (BDL) Le passé simple est plus proche par son sens du passé composé avec lequel **il alterne souvent**. En théorie, on emploie davantage **le passé simple pour évoquer des événements lointains**, alors qu’on emploie le passé composé pour évoquer des faits récents ou dont les conséquences ont un effet durable dans le présent. En pratique, toutefois, le passé composé empiète souvent sur les emplois du passé simple; il l’a même remplacé complètement à l’oral.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - C’est en 1938 que naquit ma mère.
> - Le commentaire de Martin a changé ma façon de voir les choses.

Je dirais, personnellement, qu'un retour au passé simple après avoir utilisé le passé composé ne passe pas comme un effet de style incongru dans certains cas ; il ne me semble pas alors être une anomalie.

(*exemple de user **LPH***)

- Je **suis allé** à la plage pour me détendre et il y **avait** Jean sur le sable en train de somnoler. J'**ai pris** un seau de sable que son fils **avait laissé** près d'un château de sable à moitié détruit et je le lui **ai versé** sur le dos. Cela l'**a tellement surpris** qu'il en **a eu** un cri perçant : le sable **était mélangé** à de l'eau et donc plutôt froid. Il a commencé à me chasser le long de la grève. Dans ma course j'**ai eu** la malchance de ne pas voir une tranchée dans le sable ce qui en plus de me faire tomber me **causa** une sévère entorse.

Encore personnellement, je trouve incongru le passage du passé composé au passé simple dans les suites logiques (exemple ci-dessus), dans les coordinations et certaines subordinations ; il me semble nécessaire dans ces contexte de se limiter soit à l'un soit à l'autre de ces deux temps.

(exemples de user **LPH**, les phrases en italique ne sont pas d'un style acceptable.)

- Les temps ont changé, le monde a grandi, les mœurs **ont évolué**.
  *Les temps ont changé, le monde a grandi, les mœurs **évoluèrent**.*
- Il a pris du pain puis a fait ses valises et il **est parti**.
  *Il a pris du pain puis a fait ses valises et il **partis**.*
- Le coup a été si violent que la voiture s'**est retournée**.
  *Le coup a été si violent que la voiture se **retourna**.*
- Le coup **fut** si violent que la voiture se **retourna**.

- Ils ont déformé la position qui **fut créée** par le père fondateur. (*fait lointain*)
- Ils ont déformé la position qui **a été créée** par le père fondateur. (*fait plus rapproché*)

Des caractéristiques générales de l'usage mixte se trouve encore dans la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4209), cela parmi des généralités concernant son évolution et utiles pour se faire une idée des problèmes associés à l'usage de ce temps;

> D’après certains auteurs, le déclin progressif du passé simple s’est amorcé dès le XIIe siècle. À cette époque, le passé composé avait commencé à concurrencer le passé simple dans certains emplois. Au XVIe siècle, les emplois de ces deux temps se sont spécialisés : on employait le passé simple dans la narration pour évoquer des événements lointains dont on était désormais détaché; et on employait le passé composé pour évoquer des faits récents ou dont les conséquences étaient toujours liées au présent.
>
> Malgré cette spécialisation, le passé simple a continué à décliner. Puisqu’on le privilégiait pour évoquer des événements qui n’étaient pas liés au moment où l’on parle (le présent), on s’est mis à l’employer surtout à la troisième personne, les première et deuxième personnes étant plus directement associées au présent, moment de l’énonciation. Aujourd’hui, le passé simple est rarement employé aux premières et deuxièmes personnes du singulier et du pluriel; on lui préfère alors le passé composé. En outre, plus le passé simple se faisait rare, plus ses formes semblaient étranges, ce qui a sans doute rendu son emploi de plus en plus difficile.
>
> Le passé simple est cependant encore utilisé à l’écrit, principalement à la troisième personne, et ce, non seulement dans les ouvrages littéraires, mais aussi dans les textes scientifiques et journalistiques.

Answer (score 3):

Je vais tout de même tenter de répondre à ta question. Je précise être nullement un professionnel de la langue française.

Si tu racontes une histoire, tu utiliseras plutôt l'**imparfait** et le **passé simple**, les temps du récit.

L'imparfait

> L'imparfait est le temps de la description, on l'emploie pour exprimer
>   une action passée dont la durée est indéterminée.

Le passé simple

> Le passé simple est le temps de la narration, on l'emploie pour
>   exprimer une suite d'actions.

Je n'aurais pas utilisé le passé composé dans ta phrase, on voit que tu racontes quelque chose, tu exprimes une action, donc plus naturellement j'utiliserais du passé simple.

Le passé composé est lui utilisé lorsqu'on parle d'un évènement passé (contraire du présent) qui est clos. Ou alors, il sert à exprimer un événement passé dans un **discours** qui a des conséquences dans le présent.

Après tout dépend si tu écris un livre ou tu racontes quelque chose à un ami dans un e-mail. Mais le participe présent (en se levant, entraînant) est pour moi plus du registre soutenu, donc plus naturellement j'utiliserais du passé simple.

edit: d'après cette [page](http://gerbert.unblog.fr/2008/11/07/passe-simple-et-passe-compose-en-bref/)

> Le passé composé, temps du discours, est l’équivalent du passé simple,
>   à l’oral, dans les dialogues ou dans les textes narratifs qui
>   utilisent une langue proche de l’oral

Le fait d'utiliser à la fois le passé simple et le passé composé est selon moi, de ce fait, incompatible.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Donc est ce que la phrase corrigée serait : "puis il fallut rentrer. En se levant il tomba..."? Le reste du texte est au passé composé. J'exprime un souvenir, une sorte de flash back, alors que l'histoire est au présent. Tu penses que le passé simple est plus approprié ?

Comment: Ça dépend. Si c'est du langage parlé, alors oui, tu peux utiliser du passé composé.

Comment: Par exemple avec du passé composé et un registre un peu plus familier (à noter que c'est un discours (!)) : "Puis il a fallu partir. Quand il s'est levé, il est tombé et l'a entraîné dans sa chute."

Comment: oh je comprends, je ne maîtrise pas ces subtilités encore. Merci ! Dernière question, est-il possible d'avoir un texte au passé composé avec un verbe au centre au passé simple, ou sont-ils des temps mutuellement exclusifs ?

Comment: Le passé composé et le passé simple **tous les deux** des temps du récit. Le passé composé est par excellence le temps de la narration au passé en français dans les récits contemporains.

Comment: Justement, pour moi c'est soit l'un soit l'autre. Le passé composé par exemple dans un discours ou tu relates quelque chose. Et le passé simple pour le récit. Dans le langage parlé, personne n'utilise le passé simple. Après je ne suis pas auteur, je n'ai jamais vraiment fait attention à tout ça. Je dis ce qui me paraît naturel.

Comment: @Laure Donc ce qu'on dit est vrai. Le passé simple est vraiment en train de disparaître. Si on ne l'utilise plus non plus dans les récits contemporains, il n'aura plus de raison d'être. Je trouve ça assez dommage.. Mais mixer le passé composé et le passé simple dans le récit, ce qui est ici la question, je trouve ça bizarre ou alors je me trompe?

Comment: Le constat est que le passé composé a remplacé le passé simple dans la narration. Bien que je trouve certaines phrases de [cette page](http://gerbert.unblog.fr/2008/11/07/passe-simple-et-passe-compose-en-bref/) discutables, l'exemple du texte de Daudet qui de nos jours serait écrit au passé composé est une excellent illustration de l'évolution de la langue.

Comment: @Laure Voilà, cette page confirme donc ce que je dis, le passé composé à l'oral est l'équivalent du passé simple à l'écrit. C'est ce que je m'efforce de dire à Marine Galantin. Et selon moi, cela doit rester ainsi. Ils ont juste transposé le discours écrit à l'oral.

Comment: Ce n'est pas ce qui est écrit !! Il ne s'agit pas d'une transposition à l'oral. Je copie colle : « Dans un roman rédigé à notre époque, il n’aurait pas été étonnant de lire ce même extrait, cette fois au passé composé, (pourtant) temps du discours : »

Comment: Certes, c'est toutefois mon ressenti. Et je tiens au passé simple, donc...

Comment: Il suffit de [comparer les nouvelles éditions de Martine aux anciennes](https://www.fdesouche.com/1207345-martine-1987-vs-martine-2016) pour voir que la langue française est en chute libre. Elle est pas belle l'évolution?

Comment: Un j'ai pu vaut mieux que deux je pus et un vous avez pu vaut mieux que deux vous pûtes...